# Plotly Dash Error loading layout

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

Hi I am new to Dash and I was following the tutorial on the page https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started I got an error citing msgpack not installed. I installed it later and then ran the following code given on the page.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A Web Application framework for Python.
        '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data':[
                {'x':[1,2,3],'y':[2,4,1],'type':'bar','name':'SF'}
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title':'Dash Data Visualisation'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

When I go on this http://127.0.0.1:8050/ I get the following error

```
Error loading layout
```

I read the dash documentation and community help, there are some similar questions asked, but I am not able to understand them. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once again deleted all libraries and reinstalled them and also ran the code in Chrome. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

The `code` worked fine when I ran it in terminal. The link showed a `bar plot` (below). May be your `dash` installation has some missing `libraries` / `requirement` files. You could try doing either `pip install` or `conda install` the pacakges listed below from terminal.

Example on how to install using `pip`

```
$ pip install <package name here>
```

or if using `Ananconda`

```
$ conda install <package name here>
```

example:

```
$ pip install chardet==3.0.4
```

**Packages**

```
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
Cython==0.28.2
dash==0.21.0
dash-core-components==0.22.1
dash-html-components==0.10.0
dash-renderer==0.12.1
decorator==4.3.0
nbformat==4.4.0
numpy==1.14.2
pandas==0.22.0
pandas-datareader==0.6.0
plotly==2.5.1
python-dateutil==2.7.2
pytz==2018.4
requests==2.18.4
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

[image]

**Edit - 1 .........................................**

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children='Hello Dash')])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Based on the [post](https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-pythonanywhere-deployment-issue/5062) add the line below to import.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dashapp import app as application

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children='Hello Dash')])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

or

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dashapp import server as application

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children='Hello Dash')])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

or

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dashapp import server as application

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children='Hello Dash')])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

from dashapp import server as application
```

and/or change either of the following [[post]](https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-error-loading-layout/8139/5):

```
app = Dash()
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
server = app.server
```

**Edit - 2 .........................................**

[Install dash libraries](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started)

```
pip install dash==0.21.1  # The core dash backend
pip install dash-renderer==0.13.0  # The dash front-end
pip install dash-html-components==0.11.0  # HTML components
pip install dash-core-components==0.24.0  # Supercharged components
pip install plotly --upgrade  # Latest Plotly graphing library
```

and [also](https://community.plot.ly/t/importerror-no-module-named-dash/1995/2)

```
pip install dash.ly --upgrade
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I have installed all the dependencies and libraries as mentioned on the dash website. I reinstalled them and ran the command again, but the error is same. :(

Comment: what if you try `app = dash.Dash(__name__) ` in line#4 of `code`.

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: After looking at some `posts`, I've added some suggestions from `Edit-1` that may work. If that does not work, then another option would be to `uninstall` and `reinstall` `plotly`.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I did what you told. Now, I am getting an error saying no module named dashapp installed and when I tried using pip install dashapp, I got message that there is no module named dashapp

Comment: Could you try (1) the commands in 'Edit-2', (2) re-run the original `code `from question, (3) make sure the pop-up blocker in browser is off

Comment: Hi Nilesh, it's still same: 'error loading layout' I tried what you suggested

Comment: Nilesh, I uninstalled all libraries and modules and reinstalled them and the error is still the same. (

Comment: Hi Aayush, Sorry I could not be of much help. I read your post above. Glad to see that you finally got it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Dash as well and in my case, there was a problem with syntax.

I was doing this :

```
app.layout = html.Div({
```

and was getting the "Error Loading Layout"

But when I switched to this:

```
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
```

The error vanished.

Check the syntax of the main Div for any errors.

Comment: Hi Sahil and Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please format your code? You can read here on [how to format your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and here on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You get the same error when you are using dash in older shinyproxy versions. As the search will redirect you to this post I place that answer also here.

use

```
app.config.update({
'routes_pathname_prefix': os.environ['SHINYPROXY_PUBLIC_PATH'],
'requests_pathname_prefix': os.environ['SHINYPROXY_PUBLIC_PATH']
})
```

as shown [here](https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-dash-demo) and discussed [here](https://support.openanalytics.eu/t/dash-1-3-is-not-worked-is-shinyproxy/1341/6)

Answer (score 0):

Just set `debug=False` and check your logs